# Variables in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have variables (dataframes) named as df_1, df_4, df7 so forth so on up till df_55. I need to put them all in a list so it won't be just monotonous adding one after another

`frame = [f'df_{i} for i in range(1,56,3)]` - how do I further turn it into variables instead of their being strings?

Comment: You should use a list of dataframes instead of the 19 variables

Comment: How did you end up with those 55 variables in the first place? Just make them a list when you first create them.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary in stead of eval statements. just put the data frames in

```
my_df = {'var_1': df_1,  'var_2': df_2}.
```

You can access you variables later with

```
my_df['var_1']
```

Adding them to a list would be something like

```
my_list = [df for df in my_df.values()]
```

Working with eval when it is not absolutely necessary is usually not a very good idea. It makes you code hard to read and debug

Answer (score 0):

You can try using eval() I think. It will handle your code as it was not a string but a variable,
like so:

```
var_1 = 1
var_2 = 2
var_3 = 3

print([eval(f'var_{i}') for i in range(1, 4)])
```